# UIView is sizing properly in dynamic UITableViewCell only after click

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to implement something like CardViews in my `UITableView`, so every table cell has `UIView`(named cardView) and context in this `UIView`.

I'm adding shadow to every cell in `layoutSubviews()` like this:

```
cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
cardView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1)
cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
cardView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cardView.bounds).CGPath
```

But as a result I get:

[image: Screenshot]

Shadow is properly sizing only after click on it. I suppose it's the problem with dynamically cells heights, but I can't handle with this.

I created [working example](https://github.com/Nominalista/Studies/tree/master/Examples).

Comment: Use tableView:willDisplayCell:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to view controller:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cel = cell as! TableCell
    cel.setup()
}
```

Add this code to TableCell:

```
    func setup() {
    cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1)
    cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    cardView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cardView.bounds).CGPath
}
```

Comment: It's working but after refreshing view, I mean, when I start app shadow is displaying in bad size, but when I scroll to bottom and then to the top, elements on the top have good size shadow.